# Gradle version 2.1 is required

Tags: android, gradle

I imported an Android Project, but `Gradle` throws this error:

**Error:**

```
Error:(1, 0) Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 3.5.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
<a href="fixGradleVersionInWrapper">Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project</a><br><a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a>
```

**gradle-warpper.properties:**

```
#Thu Jan 18 17:48:40 CET 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'androidsvgdrawable'

dependencies {
    compile(project(':integration-android')) {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.2'
    compile('com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2') {
        exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-fragment')
        exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-media-compat')
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.5'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
    compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

ext {
    archivesBaseName = 'bitcoin-wallet'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-26'
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

    ....
```

I tried to change

> "File -> Project Structure -> Project -> "Gradle version" ".

I changed

> 4.2 to 2.10 .

Neverless it shows the error on Android Studio (recently installed).

Comment: Have you tried adding **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10'** to your dependencies list in the build.gradle file?

Comment: I tried it: `<code>apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'androidsvgdrawable'

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10'
    compile(project(':integration-android')) {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Open the gradle file and change the version

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem: 
My mistake was to open the project in Android Studio. I prefer to use the "import projects" (Android Studio starting) button.